# PHP and javascript powered contact form don't perform JSON actions after submitting form

Tags: javascript, php, json, contact-form

This is the HTML form:

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="mail.php">
          <input class="name" id="name" type="text" name="name">
          <input class="email" id="email" type="text" name="email">
          <textarea class="message" id="message" name="message"></textarea>
          <button type="submit" class="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Here is the mail.php:

```
<?php
if(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
// If email is valid
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "mail@example.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";

if(mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader)) {
    // If mail is sent
    $resp = array("status"=>1, "message"=>"Mail successfully sent.");
} else {
    // If sending failed
    $resp = array("status"=>2, "message"=>"Error with sending mail.");
}
} else {
// If email failed filter check
$resp = array("status"=>3, "message"=>"You have provided an invalid email address.");
}

// Echos the $resp array in JSON format
echo json_encode($resp);
?>
```

And the Javascript:

```
$('.form').submit(function () {
    var name = $(".name").val(),
        email = $(".email").val(),
        message = $(".message").val();
    var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&message=' + message;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status == "1") {

                            // Action one

            } else if (data.status == "2") {

                            // Action two

            } else if (data.status == "3") {

                            // Action three

            } else {

                            // Else Actions

            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

The index.html and mail.php are in the same folder and the JS file, is in a /js/ folder.
I'm wondered why it don't work and nothing happen after clicking the submit button (non of the one, two, three or else actions happen)

Comment: Do you know anything about debugging? For instance, can you tell if a request is performed at all? Can you enable PHP's error reporting?

Comment: done any debugging? checked your console for JS errors? Check a network sniffer (e.g. firebug net tab, httpfox, etc...) to see if an ajax request is actually made? put an `error` option into the ajax call in case the ajax call worked but caused an error?

Comment: @MarcB It give me this: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.